How to make an ActiveMQ Artemis consumer terminal client stay active without counting messages?
I need an ActiveMQ Artemis consumer instance running on my terminal, but there's a counter of messages that closes the broker's connection when a certain amount of messages is reached, e.g.:
Consumer ActiveMQQueue[address::queue], thread=0 wait until 1000 messages are consumed

A Kafka's consumer client always stays active only if you manually close the connection. Is there a way to achieve the same behavior in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Any feedback here?

Currently there is no way to keep the ActiveMQ Artemis CLI consumer open indefinitely. However, you can get equivalent behavior by specifying an extremely large value for message-count (e.g. 9223372036854775807 - Java's maximum long value).
I've opened ARTEMIS-4834 to implement this new functionality.

I did a shell script with a loop until the official implementation is done
while true; do 
   docker exec -it mycontainer ./bin/artemis consumer --user artemis --password artemis --destination queue://notify::intern --verbose --durable --message-count 92233720368 >> $HOME/intern.log || break
done

